# Simple Powershell Pester Test not working for $false

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

I wrote a very simple function called "Check-RegValueExists" which works as follows when executing directly from the command prompt

```
Check-RegValueExists "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "DevicePath"

Check-RegValueExists "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "Devicexxxx"

Check-RegValueExists "HKCU:\Software\Classes\message-facebook-com" "URL Protocol"
```

which outputs the following

```
True
False
False
```

which are all **correct** outcomes.

My pester test is

```
Describe 'Check-RegValueExists Tests'{

It "has valid key with valid value" {
        'Check-RegValueExists "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "DevicePath"' | Should Be $true
        } 

It "has invalid key" {
        'Check-RegValueExists "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "Devicexxxx"' | Should Be $false
        } 

It "has empty value" {
        'Check-RegValueExists "HKCU:\Software\Classes\message-facebook-com" "URL Protocol"' | Should Be $false
        } 

}
```

However only the *first test passes* and **other two fail** with following

```
[-] has invalid key 17ms
   Expected: {False}
   But was:  {Check-RegValueExists "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "Devicexxxx"}
   8:         'Check-RegValueExists "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "Devicexxxx"' | Should Be $false
   at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 8
 [-] has empty value 28ms
   Expected: {False}
   But was:  {Check-RegValueExists "HKCU:\Software\Classes\message-facebook-com" "URL Protocol"}
   12:         'Check-RegValueExists "HKCU:\Software\Classes\message-facebook-com" "URL Protocol"' | Should Be $false
   at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 12
```

I even copied and pasted first test and modified only the string to confirm but still failing. Is there a syntax error or something else?

Comment: if I change the assertion to 
`Should be $true`
then the tests pass!!! which does not make logical sense?
is $true simply testing for any value to appear or successful running of the function???

Comment: Per my answer, your main issue is you have wrapped your commands in quotes turning them in to strings. However it would help if you also added your `Check-RegValueExists` function to your question via an edit so that we can see what it does. You should make sure that it returns $true or $false and not the strings "true" or "false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is because you have wrapped your commands in single quotes, which has turned them in to strings. As a result you are testing whether each string is $true or $false and any value is considered $true.

You need to do this:

```
Describe 'Check-RegValueExists Tests'{

    It "has valid key with valid value" {
        Check-RegValueExists "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "DevicePath" | Should Be $true
    } 

    It "has invalid key" {
        Check-RegValueExists "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "Devicexxxx" | Should Be $false
    } 

    It "has empty value" {
        Check-RegValueExists "HKCU:\Software\Classes\message-facebook-com" "URL Protocol" | Should Be $false
    } 
}
```

Comment: OMG, wow, how thick could I be, your 100% right, thank you.  I was following a tutorial and in that they seemed to be doing everything in quotes and then when i tried something for myself I just followed the convention.  Man I feel stupid.

Comment: Also, you could use `| Should -BeTrue` or `| Should -BeFalse` as well.